# Prove $T(n)=2T(\dfrac{n}{2})+\Theta(n\log{n})=\Theta(n\log^2{n})$ using induction

Tags: time-complexity, algorithm-analysis, recurrence-relation, recursion, induction

Please first take a brief look at [my previous question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/162565/prove-tn-10t-fracn3n-sqrtn-thetan-lg-310-using-induction). Here I want to do something similar but for $T(n)=2T(\dfrac{n}{2})+\Theta(n\log{n})$. I know the answer is $T(n)=\Theta(n\log^2{n})$ and I want to prove it using induction. I reached this assuming for $m<n$, we have $T(m)\leq cm\log^2{m}$:

$\begin{align*}
T(n)=2T(\frac{n}{2})+\Theta(n\log{n})&\leq 2(c\dfrac{n}{2}\log^2{\frac{n}{2}})+\Theta(n\log{n})\\
&= cn(\log{n}-1)^2+\Theta(n\log{n})\\
&=cn(\log^2n-2\log{n}+1)+\Theta(n\log{n})\\
&=cn\log^2n+cn-2cn\log{n}+\Theta(n\log{n})
\end{align*}$

At this point I can't go further. Also maybe we can reach $T(n)\leq cn\log^2n+cn+\Theta(n\log{n})$. But how can I reach $T(n)\leq cn\log^2n$? I tried to use stronger induction hypothesis like $T(m)\leq cm\log^2m-dm$ but I couldn't succeed. How can I show that? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: When doing such a proof, you should get rid of the $\Theta$, since it hides information, and can be a source of error (see [this post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/160559/false-proofs-that-look-correct/160568#160568))

Answer (score 1):

Let $c$ be the constant for the $\Theta$ expression, and show that $T(n) \leq c n \log^2 n$.

By induction, assume $n \geq 2$.

$\begin{align}
T(n) &= 2T(n/2) + cn \log n\\
     &\leq 2(c \frac n 2 \log^2 \frac n 2)) + cn \log n \text{ (by I.H.)}\\
     &= cn \log \frac n 2 \log \frac n 2 + c n \log n\\
     &= cn (\log n - 1)(\log n - 1) + cn \log n\\
     &= cn (\log^2 n - 2\log n + 1) + cn \log n\\
     &= cn \log^2 n - 2cn\log n + cn + cn \log n\\
     &= cn \log^2 n - cn\log n + cn\\
     &= cn \log^2 n + cn (1- \log n)\\
     &\leq cn \log^2 n
\end{align}$

Comment: Actually, you proved that $T(n) =\mathcal{O}(n(\log n)^2)$, not $\Theta$. You should add a comment that the lower bound can be found similarly.

Answer (score 0):

Define S(m) = T(2^n). Write down a recursive formula for S(m) and solve it. Use the result to solve T(n).